# Dynamic routes from database in older version of node

Tags: javascript, express

I am using  Node.js v ~4.

I am trying to build routes by using objects from database. This is  my logic:

```
  for (page of pages) {
    app.get(`/${page.path}`, (req, res)=> {
      res.render('test', {
        page:page,
      })
    })
  }
```

However , no matter which url I access, I always get contents from last object in database.

So urls work, but code inside `app.get()` callback function is not working properly. For example `page` variable is invalid, last object is displayed, rather than one matching path. If I would add this code:

```
console.log(req.url);
console.log(page.path);
```

as first line inside callback function, I would get next output:

Hitting first url:

```
/test01
test03
```

Hitting second url:

```
/test02
test03
```

Is there more convenient approach for dynamic routes and pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need an to use `let` on your variable being iterated over to preserve the scope - else it'll always bind the route to the last item being iterated over:</strike>

Since `let` isn't supported in node, use an IIFE:

```
for (page of pages) {
    (function(p) {
        app.get(`/${p.path}`, (req, res)=> {
            res.render('test', {
                page:p,
            })
        })
    })(page)
}
```

Comment: But `let` is not supported in Node ~4 (which is current stable) right?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
router.get('/:page', function (req, res) {
    var page = req.params.page;
    if (pages.indexOf(page) === -1) res.redirect('/');
    else res.render('index', {title: page});
});
```